# Which UK political parties support legal aid for unfair dismissal tribunals?

Tags: law, united-kingdom, conservative-party

The Conservative Party recently took away worker rights to financial support for unfair dismissal tribunals in the United Kingdom. Which parties support reintroducing financial support and what are their specific positions?

Comment: I believe you might have got this mixed up with the introduction of tribunal fees as in: https://www.gov.uk/employment-tribunals/make-a-claim rather than removing any rights. There is little point in looking at party policies now because they haven't had the chance to pass new policies (this happens in the autumn party conference season) since the 2015 General Election, but the Labour Party have said they will reverse Government policy on this if they win in 2020.

Comment: I wonder if there may be renewed scope here given opposition motions are likely to be comparatively stronger post hung parliament, and require only a comparitively small number of decenting PMs on the ruling party back benches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Labour Party has a manifesto](http://www.labour.org.uk/page/-/Images/manifesto-2017/Labour%20Manifesto%202017.pdf) commitment to "Abolish employment tribunal
fees" as part of their 20 point plan for fairness at work.

More generally they promised "We will review the legal aid means
tests, including the capital test for
those on income-related benefits." and to "consider the
reinstatement of other legal aid
entitlements after receiving the final
recommendations of the [Access to
Justice Commission led by Lord Bach](http://www.fabians.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Access-to-Justice_final_web.pdf)."

It is worth noting that, unlike a court, representative at employment tribunals are often not lawyers. Union officers or advice centre workers can act as representatives. Lawyers are often not as well placed as a trained Union rep to spot errors made by an employer. [Sourse](https://worksmart.org.uk/work-rights/enforcing-your-rights/legal-routes/who-can-represent-me-tribunal)

Comment: The question is: Is DUP for employment tribunal fees? If yes, Labour will try to get a law passed, just to piss of the DUP, and there will be some Tories voting with them. Just as making abortions free for women from Northern Ireland (as for everyone else)

Comment: Since the question was asked on May 31st, I don't think the position of the DUP is relevant at all. The question has nothing to do with the realpolitik of the minority government, but about the stated policies of the political parties.